# Whats the formula to get the page numbers for pagination?

Tags: php, pagination, formula

This question is relevant for a lightweight pagination script I am busy writing.

I have the total items and the page limit for every page. for example 15 items in total but I would like to paginate on 10. This means there are 2 pages. How do I get to that using a formula?

I am using `ceil( $total / $page_limit )` at the moment is that right?

Comment: Looks right to me, you want to use Ceil since you have to have full pages, and the last page would carry your leftovers/remainders.

Comment: I think it the number of rows divided by the rows per page, so that would be correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am using ceil( $total / $page_limit ) at the moment is that right?

Yes, it is. If there is nothing to round (e.g. if the outcome is not a float) it will simply return the outcome. If the outcome is a float, it will round it up (next highest integer value), so you'll have one page with less items than the rest, but that shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 4):

yes, it's right. 15/10 = 1.5. that ceiled is 2

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure where you are at the moment with a code, but you need to do little more to create a pagination process, i would suggest to google some simple php pagination code and use that in your code.

check this one for help! http://php.about.com/od/phpwithmysql/ss/php_pagination.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you find proper solution of the pagination then you can use this

TotalPage=(TotalRecords/PageSize)+((TotalRecords%PageSize)>0)?1:0)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).